# Preprocessing tsibble to run time series models from fable package

Tags: r, fable-r, tsibble

I am trying to run some models on some monthly time series data. The times series data are not of equal length and also not starting/ending from/in the same month. What I have is a numeric month column  and a numeric year column. I have created a time series from those two variables and made a `tsibble` out of it so that I can use the `fable` package. This is what I am doing to process the time series data,

I am posting a simulated data here.

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)

# Simulated data
id <- c(rep (222, 28), rep(111, 36), rep(555, 16))
year <- c(rep(2014, 12), rep(2015, 12), rep(2016, 4), 
          rep(2014, 12), rep(2015, 12), rep(2016, 12), 
          rep(2015, 12), rep(2016, 4))
mnt <- c(seq(1, 12, by = 1), seq(1, 12, by = 1), seq(1, 4, by = 1),
         seq(1, 12, by = 1), seq(1, 12, by = 1), seq(1, 12, by = 1),
         seq(1, 12, by = 1), seq(1, 4, by = 1))
value <- rnorm(80, mean = 123, sd = 50)
dataf <- data.frame(id, mnt, year, value)
```

To make it a `tsibble` I am converting my month variable `mnt` into a character,

```
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 1] <- "Jan"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 2] <- "Feb"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 3] <- "Mar"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 4] <- "Apr"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 5] <- "May"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 6] <- "Jun"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 7] <- "Jul"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 8] <- "Aug"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 9] <- "Sep"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 10] <- "Oct"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 11] <- "Nov"
dataf$mnt[dataf$mnt == 12] <- "Dec"
```

Adding month and year together

```
dataf %>% unite("time", mnt:year, sep = " ")
```

Make a tsibble

```
tsbl <- as_tsibble(dataf, index = time, key = id)
```

At this point, I am having this error,

```
> tsbl <- as_tsibble(dataf, index = time, key = id)
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

The remaining codes are this,

```
# Fitting arima 
fit <- tsbl %>%
  fill_gaps(b = 0) %>% 
  model(
    arima = ARIMA(value),
  )
fit

# One month ahead forecast
fc <- fit %>%
  forecast(h = 1)
fc

# Accuracy measure
accuracy_table <- accuracy(fit)
```

Any idea how to preprocess my data to run forecasting models from `fable` package?

Answer (score 1):

You have two small issues where you are creating the `time` column. The first is that you aren't reassigning your results back to the `dataf` dataframe, but only posting results to the console. Resolving that will cure your error that you posted.

The next piece is that you'll need a compatible data type. A character isn't quite enough, and you'll want something like the `tsibble` function `yearmonth()` to get the job done. For that, you'll see I flipped the order of your `unite()` call.

The relevant piece:

```
dataf <- dataf %>% unite("time", c(year, mnt), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(time = yearmonth(time))
```